# Sitecore Powershell to change Sitecore Item Fields Value by CSV File

Tags: powershell-extensions

How to change Sitecore Item field value by csv file with Sitecore PowerShell script .

As I have a Title property to be change for thousand of items in Sitecore Media Library. So I want to export existing Item Field Value in csv/excel file with Item Id and FieldId and Field Value for back up and change the Field Value by importing CSV File with Sitecore PowerShell Script. Please let me know if there are any other alternative solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think normally we use either the `PowerShell` script or `Sitecore API` (using c# code) to do the operation in bulk on multiple items.

But you can also check this tool if you want to update items in Bulk. This is called "**Sitecore Bulk Item Editor**"

Here is the link.

https://www.xcentium.com/blog/2019/09/20/sitecore-bulk-item-editor

Maybe this can help you to update the fields.